# How to keep an absolute positioned item at the bottom of the site even if there is vertical scrolling?

Tags: css

I have a footer that has position absolute:

```
#footer {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    height: 43px;
    padding:0;
    background-color: #333333;
    width:100%;
    color:#737373;
    text-align:center;
}
```

I've noticed that if I do vertical scrolling the footer stays exactly in the same place (it doesn't scroll along).

Any suggestions to fix this?

Comment: This should not be the case. Can you post your HTML and CSS markup on [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gD8nY/), if you squish the window down so the footer should overlay the text, you'll see it stays fixed to the bottom of the page. It uses `position: fixed;`

Answer (score 0):

```
#footer {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;/*add this*/
    height: 43px;
    /*padding:0;*//*no need this*/
    background-color: #333333;
    width:100%;
    color:#737373;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Well that deals with horizontal scrolling but not vertical.