# How can I float a div at the bottom of the screen in IE?

Tags: html, css

I wish to float a DIV container at the bottom of the user's screen, it should always float when the user scrolls

Tried using:

```
position: fixed;
bottom: 0px;
```

This works fine for Firefox, but not for IE !!

Any ideas on how to get it working in IE

Update, used (referred from http://tagsoup.com/cookbook/css/fixed/bottom/):

```
<html>
<body>
<style>
body
    {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 8em 0;
    color: #000;
    background: #fff;
    font-size: 1em;
    }
  div#fixedbox
    {
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 8em;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    color: #000;
    background: #ddd;
    }
  div#content
    {
    padding: 1em;
    }

@media screen
  {
  body>div#fixedbox
    {
    position: fixed;
    }
  }

</style>


<div id="content" style="width: 500px; height: 1200px">dfdf</div>
<div id="fixedbox"> The quick brown fox is stuck in this box. </div>
</body>
</html>
```

But the problem continues..

Thanks
Akash

Comment: what version(s) of IE are you supporing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/971123/css-fixed-to-bottom-and-centered

Comment: It would be useful to see more code. Also, this has been answered quite a bit in the past. Perhaps this would be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991048/how-to-keep-an-absolute-positioned-item-at-the-bottom-of-the-site-even-if-there/7991172#7991172

Comment: There's your problem, Akash. Why are you using IE6?

Comment: Finally got it working using: http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/fixedPosition.html  thanks for your help guys

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely positioned elements outside of div.content will be fixed in respect to the viewport, absolutely positioned elements inside of div.content will behave normally. This works in version 5.0 and higher of ie on windows and is the most stable solution available.

Click "start playing", view the source, and learn...

http://tagsoup.com/cookbook/css/fixed/bottom/

```
body
    {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 8em 0;
    }
  div#fixedbox
    {
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 8em;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    }
{
  body>div#fixedbox
    {
    position: fixed;
    }
```